# How to encode image to h264 in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

For some reason, I want to encode image frame to h264 in android. In order to get a better performance, I used ffmpeg with android ndk to encode image. I'm so strange that it's easy to decode h264 frame to image while it's so hard to encode image to h264 frame. When I try to use avcodec_encode_video2 function the eclipse always shows a message 
An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyApp".
java.lang.NullPointerException
which make me crazy.
I'm also so angry that the android ndk do not show any message useful to tell me what happen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

h264 encoder is not an integral part of ffmpeg. Usually we use the opensource x264 encoder, but this has significant legal consequences. x264 is GPL, while usually builds of ffmpeg are LGPL. You can build ffmpeg with x264, or use x264 standalone.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm a new man in the part, can you teach me how to build ffmpeg with x264? I use the.so file from internet.

Comment: Maybe you prefer to avoid all this hassle and use the Java API which is part of Android? According to the [table](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core), h264 encoder is supported by MediaCodec on since Android 3.0.

Comment: It may work but I have finished the code in Windows with ffmpeg and now I want to use the code in android. What's more, I have compiled a ffmpeg with x264 following the steps from internet but it didn't work. I have set the enable-encoder=x264.